# Strange behavior using & in if statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

While solving one of the problems, I found a strange behavior.

```
def sortedSquares(nums: list[int]) -> list[int]:   
    pointer = len(nums) - 1
    
    for i in range(pointer):
        if nums[pointer] > abs(nums[0]) & nums[pointer-1] < abs(nums[0]):
            nums.insert(pointer, abs(nums[0]))
            nums.remove(nums[0])
            pointer -= 1
        elif nums[pointer] < abs(nums[0]):
            nums.insert(pointer+1, abs(nums[0]))
            nums.remove(nums[0])
            pointer -= 1
        else:
            pointer -= 1

    return [num ** 2 for num in nums]
```

It's working fine for the following input example:

```
assert sortedSquares([-5, -3, -2, -1]) == [1, 4, 9, 25]
```

But it's not working for this:

```
assert sortedSquares([-3, 0, 2]) == [0, 4, 9]
```

Somehow the ELIF statement was skipped during the first iteration. But when I changed bitwise & operator to logical AND in the IF statement - it started to work.

Could someone please explain what's going on here?

Sorry if it's a duplicate. I have been trying to find an explanation but found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is not strange. You should check [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). You missed `(...) & (...)`:

```
if nums[pointer] > abs(nums[0]) & nums[pointer-1] < abs(nums[0]):
```

should be

```
if (nums[pointer] > abs(nums[0])) & (nums[pointer-1] < abs(nums[0])):
#  ^---        HERE          ---^   ^---        HERE            ---^
```

Output

```
# Before
>>> sortedSquares([-3, 0, 2])
[0, 9, 4]

# After
>>> sortedSquares([-3, 0, 2])
[0, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), `&` has higher precedence than `>` and `<`. Thus

```py
nums[pointer] > abs(nums[0]) & nums[pointer-1] < abs(nums[0])
```

is evaluated as

```py
nums[pointer] > (abs(nums[0]) & nums[pointer-1]) < abs(nums[0])
```

which is not the same as when you use (the correct) logical `and`, as that has lower precedence than `>` and `<` and thus the statement evaluates as you expect as:

```py
(nums[pointer] > abs(nums[0])) and (nums[pointer-1] < abs(nums[0]))
```